# Strange NSDateFormatter behaviour

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format a handful of dates like so:

```
 NSArray *dateStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"09/03/2013 07",
                            @"09/13/2013 07",
                            @"10/21/2013 07",
                            @"11/05/2013 07",
                            @"11/19/2013 07",
                            @"12/06/2013 07",
                            @"01/17/2014 07",
                            @"01/21/2014 07",
                            @"03/04/2014 07",
                            @"04/11/2014 07",
                            @"04/25/2014 07",
                            @"05/01/2014 07",
                            @"05/20/2014 07", nil];

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"DD/mm/yyyy hh"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dateStrings objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

When I get the log, here's what is see: 2013-01-01 12:21:00 +0000
This is from the date: 10/21/2013 07

Why is this? I'm guessing it's a problem with my formatter syntax, but it looks fine to me.

Thank you.

Comment: samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be "dd/MM/yyyy hh"? I didn't look it up, but IIRC month is capital M and day is lowercase d.

Comment: I made the change, and it returns nil now. My object at index 2 is in the proper format for the new... `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh"];`

Comment: 10/21/2013... I don't think there is a 21st month :)

I guess it should be MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: However, hours are still not working. For `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH"];`,     "2013-10-21 11:00:00 +0000", is returned. I want 7:00 AM, not 11.

Comment: That's due to the timezone. You're probably in GMT-4, so 11AM is the same as 7AM -4000.